# free ramdisk for windows 64bit

Tags: windows, 64-bit, ramdisk

Is there a free ramdisk utility for windows 2003 64bit OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[On SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/34388/whats-the-best-ramdisk-for-windows) they're suggesting either the freeware [Dataram](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk) (free only up to 4GB) or the GPLv2-opensourced [ImDisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImDisk), which sounds really cool!
Other anwers also suggest this [banchmark page](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2009/12/08/12-ram-disk-software-benchmarked-for-fastest-read-and-write-speed/).

Comment: Thankyou very much, ImDisk worked flawlessly.